# what are the orders that took more than a day to deischarge, i have date of order and date of discharge

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I started my career in data analysis and I have to use sql statements in day to day work. I am learning but need to also provide some quick answers. So I thought I will ask some questions in this group.

I would need help to write sql query in getting the orders that took more than one or tow days (based on rquirement) to discharge from the location.

Type of activity column represents 1,2,3,4

```
1-Order placed
2-Order discharged
```

Date is recorded in the column date in the corresponding row

Now i would like to call for all the orders that to took more than certain number of days 'n'

This is an example of the table how my table looks like.

Activities Table

```
|Order Nr|  activity|date|
|     1  |     1    | date1|    order placed
|     1  |     3    | date2|    order approved
|     1  |     4    | date3|    order packed
|     1  |     2    | date4|   order discharged
```

Comment: Thanks Siyual for formating my questions! Greetings, Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get order placements with

```
select * from activities where activity = 1
```

and you can probably guess how to get order discharges :-)

So combine the two and keep only rows with too high a difference:

```
select p.order_nr, p.date as placed, d.date as discharged
from (select * from activities where activity = 1) p
join (select * from activities where activity = 2) d
  on d.order_nr = p.order_nr and datediff(d.date, p.date) > 1;
```

You can get the same with an aggregation per order:

```
select 
  order_nr, 
  any_value(case when activity = 2 then date end) as placed,
  any_value(case when activity = 1 then date end) as discharged
from activities
group by order_nr
having datediff(any_value(case when activity = 2 then date end), 
                any_value(case when activity = 1 then date end)) > 1;
```

In case you want to include open orders, you'd do almost the same. For orders without a discharged record it is possible that this will be entered today, so orders placed yesterday may still be fine whereas orders placed before are open too long already. So in case there is no dicharged record we want to pretend there is one with date = today.

Query #1:

```
select p.order_nr, p.date as placed, d.date as discharged
from (select * from activities where activity = 1) p
left join (select * from activities where activity = 2) d
  on d.order_nr = p.order_nr and datediff(coalesce(d.date, curdate()), p.date) > 1;
```

Query #2:

```
select 
  order_nr, 
  any_value(case when activity = 2 then date end) as placed,
  any_value(case when activity = 1 then date end) as discharged
from activities
group by order_nr
having datediff(any_value(case when activity = 2 then date end), 
                coalesce(any_value(case when activity = 1 then date end), curdate())) > 1;
```

Comment: Hello Thorsten, Thank you very much! I will let you know right after checking my results. Greetings, Sai

Comment: You are welcome. I just noticed, I confused activity values. I've corrected them now (activity 2 instead of 4 for discharges). My queries don't find orders that were written before yesterday and have no discharge record, yet, by the way. If you want to include these you'd need an outer join and coalesce in the first query and a coalesce in the second. Tell me, if I shall include these in my answer.

Comment: I noticed the order number, its not abig problem. It would be nice if you could add the Outer Join. I really appreciate :)

Comment: Thanks! its very clear! :) I will try now and let you know :)

Comment: datediff doenst work. Date looks like 20170221. throws an error! Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you store the dates as strings??? Use `str_to_date(datestring, '%Y%m%d')` then to convert them to date. (But it would be way better to change the table design then. It's a bad idea to store dates as strings and not as dates. As you already see.)

Comment: Great, I really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`Not exists` is one method:

```
select a.*
from activities a
where a.activity = 'placed' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from activities a2
                  where a2.activity = 'discharged' and
                        a2.ordernum = a.ordernum and
                        a2.date >= a.date and
                        a2.date <= a.date + interval 1 day
                 );
```

Comment: Hello Gordon! I really appreciate your quick reply. I am sorry i didnt understand the select query after NOT EXISTS! Thank you very much! Greetings, Sai

Comment: @Sai: This translates to: where not exists a discharged record for the same ordernum with a date later than one day after the placement date.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what does `select 1` returns?

Comment: It returns 1. But well, this is a dummy; `[NOT] EXISTS` simply checks whether the subquery returns records or not. You could just as well `select *` for instance, but many people make it a habit to select a constant instead, which works in any query, even aggregations. You can also make this `select 'I exist'` if you find this more readable :-)

Comment: But as we are talking about; shouldn't that be `a2.date <= a.date + interval 1 day`? Because you are fine with dischargements within one day after placement. Or `EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXISTS`. I guess Gordon made a mistake there.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . Yes I did make a mistake.  Fixed it.

Comment: I tried Thoersten's first method and Gordons Method. The number of records by both the methods differ. Thoerstens method results more than Gordons method. Any clue? Greetings